# SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "DBName" requested by the login

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have the following connection string in ASP.NET Core, but I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open
>   database "DBName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'admin-PC\admin'.

In SQL log

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. and Login failed for user
>   'admin-PC\admin'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified
>   database 'DBName'. [CLIENT: ]

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CoreConnection": "server=.;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? It's pretty clear. Have you checked the SQL Server's logs for the authentication failure reason?

Comment: yes i get `Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.` and `Login failed for user 'admin-PC\admin'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DBName'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`

Comment: Sounds like the database is in single user mode

Comment: Thanks @Larnu how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you saying it is? If so `ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET MULTI_USER;`

Comment: when i try to Alter MULTI_USER i get `User does not have permission to alter database 'DBName', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
`

Comment: Does `admin-PC\admin` have access to SQL Server? Is that user in the `Administrators` group?

Comment: i can connect using management studio, create database...

Comment: how can i check ` Is that user in the Administrators group`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you deleted your database?
I had the same problem. So, if you have created migration, just run
`update-database` in your Package Manager Console.